# How to change layout in magento 2.2.0

Tags: layout, magento2.2.0

I am using Magento blank theme, I want to change the layout on Product detail page, on product details page the default layout is 1column layout. How to change from 1column layout to 2columns-left layout. Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you create any custom theme?

Comment: I have not created any theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following : 
In your Layout file inside the theme :

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\ThemeName\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    .............
    .............
```

Another option in your Layout file inside the custom module:

app\code\Vendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    .............
    .............
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change containers from layout.xml 
If you are working on default theme "Luma" then you can find layout.xml in  "\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout". Otherwise you can find it in your theme "\vendor_name\theme_name\magento_theme\view\frontend\layout"

Thanks